# Listen for Windows Accessibility Events from C#

Tags: c#, windows, accessibility

I am trying to write an application that would listen for events outside of my application in C# but I'm having a lot of trouble finding any information about this.  The idea is to listen for a click or a focus change and at a specific time get some information about the control that the user is interacting with.  I would want information such as the accessibilityID, control type, name, tree structure for that element, and any other information that might be relevant.  I would like to build something like [Inspect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I would then take the data and do different manipulations on it later.

Being a bit new to C# I'm not sure exactly where to look.  I imagine that there should be some sort of event that would give me the information I need but I can't find it.  If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Check out the [System.Windows.Automation namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Check out [UI Automation Using MSAA](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38906/UI-Automation-Using-Microsoft-Active-Accessibility) to get more links/ideas.

Comment: An example tracking focus changes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11712947/517852

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely going to need to hook into low-level Window events...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: There is already a wrapper class for all this: System.Windows.Automation.