# Event that triggers BEFORE my form loses focus

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to be alerted before my entire form loses focus. The Deactivate event only triggers after it loses focus. LostFocus and Leave are only for controls.

I have also tried overriding WndProc but this only triggers after the message has been processed.

overriding PreProcessMessage only can be used for keyboard stuff, not form deactivation.

Comment: Why isn't the Deactivate event satisfactory?

Comment: @JeremyThompson because it triggers after the form has already been deactivated. I need to do stuff to it that requires the form to be activated.

Comment: What stuff is needed for the form to be active? *SendKeys?*

Comment: @JeremyThompson changing the Input Language

Comment: You will get more responses and better answers if you [edit] your question showing the code to change Input Language, because I think there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

**Dodgy Method**

Even though this is a quick and hacky way of doing it, changing Input Language is unnatural to start with..

```
private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Form)sender).Activate();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.ActiveControl.Name);
    //Change Input Language here..

    //Alt TAB to set focus to the application selected 5 milliseconds ago
    SendKeys.SendWait("%{TAB");
}
```

**Correct and orthadox method**

[How to monitor focus changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711400/how-to-monitor-focus-changes) and [C#: Detecting which application has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183541/c-detecting-which-application-has-focus)

Its using the [Automation framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation(v=vs.110).aspx), Add references to `UIAutomationClient` and `UIAutomationTypes` and use [`Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automation.addautomationfocuschangedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx), e.g.:

```
public class FocusMonitor
{
    public FocusMonitor()
    {
        AutomationFocusChangedEventHandler focusHandler = OnFocusChanged;
        Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(focusHandler);
    }

    private void OnFocusChanged(object sender, AutomationFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AutomationElement focusedElement = sender as AutomationElement;
        if (focusedElement != null)
        {
            int processId = focusedElement.Current.ProcessId;
            using (Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(process.ProcessName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK!  this is close.   It works sometimes.  But sometimes it causes my form to be reactivated. Is there any way to make it more reliable?

Comment: I was able to improve it by using Send instead of SendWait, sometimes it still reactivates my form(tabs out of the window i just activated).   I think the problem is the code isn't being run fast enough and the other tab opens before the Deactivate method executes.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed if it you click on Desktop for example the app still is active. I'll have a think about a less hacky way than *SendKeys*

Comment: From my tests the new updated one is happening after the deactivate event.  So after the form already lost focus.  :(

Comment: Ok, I finally got a solution that works, not to brag but Its pretty clever i think. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, this hack works perfectly.

```
    private void MyForm_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);  //delay to allow external tab time to open
        Form f1 = new Form();  //create a new form that will take focus, switch input, then terminate itself
        f1.Shown += new EventHandler((s, e1) => { f1.Activate();  InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.DefaultInputLanguage; f1.Close(); });
        f1.Show();
    }
```

EDIT: upon further testing I have found this to be equally unreliable. It doesn't seem like there is a good way to do this at all.

For now I am tracking the mouse and keyboard to detect when the user is about to deactivate it.  Obviously a mouse and keyboard hook is a horrible solution but its the only reliable solution so far.