# Windows 10 language change pop up menu focus problem in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-10, focus

I have a C# class that's responsible for monitoring focus changes globally.

It works via `SetWinEventHook` with `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372055/detect-active-window-changed-using-c-sharp-without-polling) question for details.

Everything works really well, but there's a weird problem...

When you're changing language on Windows 10 via `Alt+Shift` a little menu pops up with the languages enabled on your system that you can select from.

Well, guess what, that thing sends a focus change event too...

The weird part is - the process that had the focus before the language change kinda... doesn't lose it? Because after that pop up menu disappears you don't get the focus change event for the window that was focused.

For example, I'm typing text in Notepad++ (`notepad++` process name) and my program registered that, when I go and change language via `Alt+Shift` that little pop up menu sends the focus event (`explorer` process name) and upon disappearing Notepad++ doesn't send the focus event!

And even if I do something in Notepad++ afterwards, I will not get the focus event for it...

Only focusing on some other window (not Notepad++) will send the focus change event.

**How do I overcome this issue?**

Keep in mind, that I'm still interested in `explorer` process, because File Explorer has that name. So, I can't just ignore all processes that are `explorer`

P.S. I also used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711400/how-to-monitor-focus-changes) way of global focus monitoring, but it does the same thing.

Comment: A little more info: the `explorer` process for that pop-up menu is the same that is used for File Explorer...

Comment: I can reproduce this issue in Win32 C++ application and I'll consult the related engineer.