# How to check if my application is the Windows activate form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I've created some global Hot keys for my application and I want them to work only if my application is active. (It should not work if my application is not the active form).

So how can I check if my `C#` winform application is the active form among all the other windows applications?

I tried

```
if(this.Focused)
  //Do somthing
```

But it's not working

Comment: unclear what you are asking..please put some light

Comment: @utility Questions has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handle, out int processId);

public static bool Activates()
{
    var x = GetForegroundWindow();
    if (x == IntPtr.Zero) {
        return false;      
    }

    var y = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
    int i;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(x, out i);

    return i == y;
}
```

You can also refer: [C#: Detecting which application has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183541/c-detecting-which-application-has-focus)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows API function `GetForegroundWindow` and `GetWindowText`.

**GetForegroundWindow** :

The GetForegroundWindow function returns a handle to the window with which the user is currently working.

**GetWindowText**:

The GetWindowText function copies the text of the specified window's title bar (if it has one) into a buffer.

Add below code to declare API functions :

```
[ DllImport("user32.dll") ]
        static extern int GetForegroundWindow();

[ DllImport("user32.dll") ]
        static extern int GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
```

Start a timer :

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            GetActiveWindow();
        }
```

**Active window function :**

```
private void GetActiveWindow()
    {

        const int nChars = 256;
        int handle = 0;
        StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);

        handle = GetForegroundWindow();

        if ( GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0 )
        {
            this.captionWindowLabel.Text = Buff.ToString();
            this.IDWindowLabel.Text = handle.ToString();
        }

    }
```